# Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Feature with Id 'xxxxx-xxx' is not installed in this farm, and cannot be added to this scope

Tags: web-part, workflow, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, feature-activation

while installing a feature, VS ouput the error: 
Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Feature with Id 'xxxxxxx-xxxx' is not installed in this farm, and cannot be added to this scope.

The warning error  gives me a Guid the it's not present inside the solution.

Does anyone knows what does that Guid represent?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Thats the unique identifier for a feature which your own feature depends on. It might not be a feature of your own solution but a sharepoint internal feature. Try to google the feature id and see if you find something.
Also, you can try to query for all features installed on your farm using powershell
http://geekswithblogs.net/bjackett/archive/2009/10/08/powershell-script-find-all-sharepoint-features-installed-on-farm.aspx
Hope it helps